# Data is not written

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making my react application strictly according to the lessons. But there was such an error, I tried to figure it out all day, but I have no idea why this is happening. The main point is that I have the `addProduct` function located in the `ModalAddProduct` component, in fact, it just collects data and passes it to the `addProduct` function, which is located in the `redux / state.js` folder, this function simply adds the data passed to it via callback to the state object, in which stores all products. But the problem is that no data is being written. Although when dabbing it is clear that the data comes in, but is not pushed into the array. I tried with other data, same error. Moreover, when debugging, if you hover courses over an array, it shows the added products, but they are not in the array itself (there are screenshots). Also, when rendering on changes was added according to the lessons, the application shows the products, but after the reboot they disappear, since they were not registered in the array of products

```
export let addProduct = (data) => { 
debugger;

 state.mainPage.products.push(data);
 rerenderF(state);
}
export default state;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import state from './redux/state';
import {addProduct} from './redux/state';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App state={state} addProduct={addProduct}/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './Components/Navbar/Nav';
import Footer from './Components/Footer/Footer';
import AdminProducts from './Pages/AdminProducts'; 

import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const  App = (props) => {
  return (
     <div>
       <Nav></Nav>
       <Route path="/products" 
       render={ () => <AdminProducts products={props.state.mainPage.products} addProduct={props.addProduct}/>} />
       <Footer></Footer>
     </div>
    
  );
}
export default App;
```

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        <ProductsList products={props.products} addProduct={props.addProduct} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function ProductList(props) {
    return (
       <div className="container">
           <AddProductButton />
           <ModalAddProduct addProduct={props.addProduct}/>
          <div className="row"> 
               {props.products.map( product => {
                   return <ProductAdminCard  product={product} />
               })}
          </div>
       </div>
    );
}
```

```
import { checkPropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

function ModalAddProduct(props) {
    const urlPhoto = 'https://sun9-56.userapi.com/impg/46d6OEAguHzOvhD8gFvtuaKJpgbB2HdpCrR2wQ/rXhMbv1AJnE.jpg?size=800x800&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=1c6396244ef85dbe1ab426308018ddca';
    let setPrice = React.createRef();
    let setProducer = React.createRef();
    let setType = React.createRef();
    let setSizes = React.createRef();
    let setDescription = React.createRef();
    let setTags = React.createRef();
    let setPhoto = React.createRef();

    const addProduct = () => {
      const data = {
                id: 9,
                "urlPhoto": urlPhoto,
                "price": `${setPrice.current.value}`,
                "producer": `${setProducer.current.value}`,
                "type": `${setType.current.value}`,
                "sizes": `${setSizes.current.value}`,
                "description": `${setDescription.current.value}`,
                "tags": `${setTags.current.value}`
      }
     props.addProduct(data);
     setPrice.current.value = '';
     setProducer.current.value = '';
     setType.current.value = '';
     setSizes.current.value = '';
     setDescription.current.value = '';
     setTags.current.value = '';
    }
    return (
    <div className="modal fade" id="addProduct" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row justify-content-center">
                  <div className="col-md-6 text-center">
                    <figure className="figure">
                        <img src={urlPhoto} className="figure-img img-fluid rounded profile-img" alt="photo" />
                      </figure>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row justify-content-center">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                         <label for="photo">Url photo</label>
                          <input className="form-control" type="text" id="photo" placeholder="URL" ref={setPhoto} />
                          <label for="price">Price</label>
                          <input className="form-control" type="text" id="price" placeholder="Enter price" ref={setPrice} />
                          <label for="producer">Producer</label>
                          <input type="text" className="form-control" id="producer" placeholder="Enter producer" ref={setProducer} />
                          <label for="type">Type</label>
                          <input type="text" className="form-control" id="type" placeholder="Enter type" ref={setType} />
                          <label for="sizes">Sizes</label>
                          <input className="form-control" type="text" id="sizes" placeholder="Enter sizes(use ',')" ref={setSizes} />
                          <label for="description">Description</label>
                          <textarea className="form-control" id="description" rows="3" ref={setDescription}></textarea>
                          <label for="tags">Tags</label>
                          <input type="text" className="form-control" id="tags" placeholder="Enter tags" ref={setTags} />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row justify-content-center">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <button className="btn general-button add-button-modal btn-block" onClick={addProduct}>Add product</button>
                    <button className="btn general-button delete-button btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">Canel</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ModalAddProduct;
```

[image]
[image]
[image]